# How to maintain array structure and keys during calcultations

Tags: php, arrays, multiplication

I have a database with rows of data where each column is a country. In this example there are 4 country (columns) and 3 rows although the number of each will change and so need to be dynamic inputs. I want to normalize each row so the min value is 0 and the max is 100 and at the same time keep the 4 x 3 array structure of the original database so I can extract rows or columns on request.

The final output will be passed to Javascript to be presented in graph form.
The code I have come up with normalizes the data correctly but the output is one long array 12 x 1 and the column names have been dropped.

I was wondering if anyone know how I could keep the same structure for `$ScoreNorm`  as for the output of `$dataA`, both presented below?

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("relevant inputs");

if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
    mysql_select_db("db-name");

    $dataArray = "SELECT * FROM data2012"
        or die(mysql_error()); 

$data2012=mysql_query($dataArray, $conn);
if(! $data2012 )
 {
 die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
 }

$ScoreNorm = array();
$dataA = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data2012))
{
$dataA[] = $row;
$max_val = max($row);
$min_val = min($row);

    foreach($row as $key => &$dataAitem)
        {
    $ScoreNorm[] = array((($dataAitem - $min_val)/($max_val - $min_val))*100);
        }
}
echo json_encode($dataA) . "<br />";
echo json_encode($ScoreNorm) . "<br />";

echo $dataA[1]['France'];
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

The output for echo json_encode($dataA) is

```
[{"China":"11.000","Australia":"8.300","France":"12.600","UK":"6.220"},{"China":"2.000","Australia":"1.000","France":"4.000","UK":"5.000"},{"China":"39548.000","Australia":"25487.000","France":"245.000","UK":"2547852.000"}]
```

Where as the output for echo json_encode($ScoreNorm) is

```
[[74.921630094],[32.6018808777],[100],[0],[25],[0],[75],[100],[1.54274187502],[0.990812162158],[0],[100]]
```

To reiterate, I would like `$ScoreNorm` to maintain the `$dataA format`. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

I have cracked the second foreach out into its own loop because I dont know what column names you are using, that and I usually have everything fetched up to this point. I am also operating under the assumption that the country name is the key, and the number is the value. If you need help with that, just let me know what the column names are in your structure, otherwise check this out:

```
$dataA = array();
$ScoreNorm = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data2012))
{

   $dataA[] = $row;

}


foreach($dataA as $dataAkey => $dataAvar){

$max_val = max($dataAvar);
$min_val = min($dataAvar);

$ScoreNormTemp=array();

    foreach($row as $country => $value)
    {

       $ScoreNormTemp[$country] = 
           array((($value - $min_val)/($max_val - $min_val))*100);

    }

$ScoreNorm[] = $ScoreNormTemp;

}
```

You are currently populating the array one dimensionally, when you need to make a new array which then gets added to the array of arrays at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating $ScoreNorm, add the row to $dataA as normal, then modify it and add it to $ScoreNorm:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data2012))
{
    $dataA[] = $row;
    $max_val = max($row);
    $min_val = min($row);

    foreach($row as &$dataAitem) {
        $dataAitem = (($dataAitem - $min_val)/($max_val - $min_val))*100;
    }
    $ScoreNorm[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure i understand correctly what u are after, but i will try none the less

```
$output_arr = new array (); //final output
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data2012))
{
$dataA[] = $row;
$max_val = max($row);
$min_val = min($row);

$row_arr = new array ();
    foreach($row as $key => &$dataAitem) // this create temp array keeping the property name
        {
           $row_arr[$key]  = normalized_value ($dataitem); //put your func here.. to get this value for this country
        }

array_push ($output_arr,$row_arr); //now add this to final output array..
}

echo json_encode ($output_arr); //should have what u seek, i hope
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if anyone know how I could keep the same structure for $ScoreNorm as for the output of $dataA

You just have to maintain the keys in the normalized array to achieve that.

```
$ScoreNorm = array();
$dataA     = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data2012)) {
    $dataA[] = $row;
    $max_val = max($row);
    $min_val = min($row);

    $rowNorm = array();    
    foreach ($row as $key => $dataAitem) {
        $rowNorm[$key] = ($dataAitem - $min_val)/($max_val - $min_val)*100;
    }
    $ScoreNorm[] = $rowNorm;
}
```

I'd recommend to round the normalized values, because it redices the length of the JSON response and the fraction not really does contain relevant information. So I would change the line

```
        $rowNorm[$key] = ($dataAitem - $min_val)/($max_val - $min_val)*100;
```

to

```
        $rowNorm[$key] = (int)round(($dataAitem - $min_val)/($max_val - $min_val)*100);
```